# Codeigniter y PhpMyadmin en Intranet

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

**Buenas, estoy queriendo hacer funcionar mi proyecto en una Intranet, el caso es que hasta ahora había utilizado Hostinger para lanzar las aplicaciones, e incluso en local con XAMPP. Pero nunca lo he hecho en la Intranet, he estado usando Codeigniter y phpMyAdmin. ¿Qué tendría que utilizar ahora? ¿Se puede hacer igualmente? Necesito orientación.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que definir un equipo de tu red como servidor principal y abrir el puerto `80` para que los otros equipos puedan acceder a el.
Normalmente te debe dejar acceder mediante la IP del servidor, puedes editar el archivo `hosts` para usar una URL de forma de local

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
ip_servidor     misitio.com
```

lo que hace esta configuración es redireccionar todas las peticiones de `misitio.com` a la ip del `servidor principal`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha quedado más claro.